# Share logic between application module and library module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have `module.gradle.kts` :

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
}
```

And `app.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to define a common configuration of `android.defaultConfig` for both `app.gradle.kts` and `module.gradle.kts` in a dedicated gradle file, such as `root.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    // What plugin to use here since this is neither an application module nor a library module ?
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Common configuration to be used by app.gradle.kts and module.gradle.kts
    }
}
```

Is there a common ancestor to "com.android.application" and "com.android.library" that can be used in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've defined my own extension function in `buildSrc/src/main/Extensions.kt`:

```
import com.android.build.api.dsl.CommonExtension

fun CommonExtension<*, *, *, *, *>.applyRootConfiguration() {
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then I can apply it in an application or a library by doing:

```
android {
    applyRootConfiguration()
}
```